# Proof that the set of integers has the least upper bound property

Tags: solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, integers

I can't seem to get the last part of my proof to *feel* right, so here's my shot at it:

$(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$ has the least upper bound property. To show this, let A be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded above. Then there is an integer $x$ such that for every $a\in A$, $a\leq x$. We claim that $x=\sup{A}$. Suppose not, taking $y=\sup{A}$, where $y<x$. Then $x-1\leq y\leq x$. However, as $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, this is a contradiction. Thus $x=\sup{A}$.

Comment: You know $x$ exists because $A$ is bounded, right?  That in no way guarantees $x \in A$ or that $x$ is its supremum.  For example, the set $\{1,2,3\}$ is bounded from above by $10$.  Also, $x-1\leq y \leq x$ is not a contradiction in the integers; $x = 2$, $y=1$ satisfies that inequality, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Your proof cannot be right. You claim that if $x$ is *any* upper bound of $A$, then $x=\sup A$. So if, say, $A=\{-2,3,15\}$ and if you take $x=10^{100}$ then since $x$ is an upper bound of $A$, $\sup A=10^{100}$. You don't believe that, do you? One of the problems with your proof takes place when you write “taking $y=\sup A$”. How do you know that such a $y$ exists? Isn't the existence of $\sup A$ what you are trying to prove?

---

One way of proving the statement is this: let $a\in A$ and let $n$ be an upper bound of $A$. You can prove the statement ($\sup A$ exists) by induction on $n-a$. If $n-a=0$, then $n\in A$ and therefore $n=\sup A$. Now, fix $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and suppose that the statement holds when $n-a=k$. Suppose that, for a certain $A$, $n-a=k+1$. Then either $n\in A$ or $n\notin A$. If $n\in A$, then $n=\sup A$. Otherwise, let $n'=n-1$. Then $n'$ is an upper bound of $A$ and, since$$n'-a=n-1-a=n-a-1=k+1=1=k,$$by the induction hypothesis, $\sup A$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

`proof-verification:`

> $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$ has the least upper bound property. `(Separate the statement and the proof.)`
>
> To show this, let A be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded above. Then there is an integer $x$ such that for every $a\in A$, $a\leq x$. `(This means x is "an" upper bound of A.)` We claim that $x=\sup{A}$. `(This is not necessarily true and your proof breaks down here. I should stop reading from here.)`
>
> `(Regardless the mistake above, there are several more in the following argument.)`
>
> Suppose not, taking $y=\sup{A}$, `(You are using the conclusion to support your argument: without showing the existence of sup A how would you "taking" y?)` where $y<x$. Then $x-1\leq y\leq x$. `(This "Then" does not make sense at all.)` However, as $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, this is a contradiction. `(There are many many examples with` $x-1\leq y\leq x$`. This is not a contradiction.)` Thus $x=\sup{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!  I missed the obvious.

$\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property.

So if $A\subset \mathbb Z$ is a non-empty set that is bounded above in $\mathbb Z$.  Then there exists an $x \in \mathbb Z$ so that $x \ge a$ for all $a\in A$.

But $x \in \mathbb R$ so $x$ is an uppper bound and $A$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb R$.  Call it $s$.

Let $1 \epsilon > 0$.  Then there is an element $a \in A$ so that $s - < s- \epsilon < a \le s$.

Now $a$ is an integer.  If $s > a$ then $a$ is not an upper bound and there is a $b \in A$ so that $s-1< a < b < s$.  And $b$ is an integer.  So $0 < b-a < 1$ but $b,a$ are integers so $b-a$ is an integer that is between $0$ and $1$.

That is impossible is $a=s$ and $s$ is an integer.

So $s$ is a least upper bound that is in $A$ so $A$ is bounded above in $\mathbb Z$.

And $\mathbb Z$ has the least upper bound property.

Read below to see how to do it without assumimg $\mathbb R$ has the l.u.b. property.  But it uses quite a bit of induction.

=======

I think you are very muddled on the concepts and definitions.  What you wrote was .... well, there are many things specifically I could point out and explain , but I think that'd be confusing and it'd be easier and actually more helpful to just call it meaningless babble.

Let $A \subset \mathbb Z $. (Assume $A $ is non-empty).

Assume $A $ is bounded above.  That means there exists a $z $ in $\mathbb Z$ so that $z \ge a$ for all $a \in A$.  We do not have any reason to believe $z $ is the least upper bound or that any upper bound exists.

Check if $z\in A$.  If it is, then if $u <z$ then $u $ can't be an upper bound because is is less $z $ which is in $A$.  So $z $ would be the least upper bound.

If $z$ is not in $A $ then all $a\in A $ strictly less than $z $ and are less than or equal to $z-1$.  So $z-1$ is Uber bound.

We then do the same thing for $z-1$.  We check if it is in $A $ if it is then it is least upper bound, if not $z-2$ is an upper bound.

We keep repeating until we get some $y $ value we test is in $A $.  How do we know that will eventually happen?

Well, $A $ is non empty so there is a $k\in A$.  And $k \le z $.  So let $n=z-k $.  After $n$ tests of whether $z-i $ is in $A $ we will eventually get to $k=z-n\in A $.

Now, we might get to $z-i\in A $ before we have to do $z-n $.  But the point is there will have to be some *first* $y=z -i\in A $ so that for all $w >y$, $w \not \in A $.

So for all $a \in A $ we know $a\le y $ so $y$ is an upper bound.  And $u <y $, $u $ can't be an upper bound because it is less than $y $ which is in $A $.  So $y $ is the least upper bound.

So a least upper bound exists.  So $\mathbb Z $ has the least upper bound property.

Actually, we've proven something stronger.  We have proven that for any set bounded above, not only does a least upper bound exists.  The least upper bound will be a member of the set.